# Can we slow down with the "when did X appear and how did they differ between editions" style questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There's now four on the top page:
[Artificers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166055/when-did-artificers-make-their-first-appearance-in-dd-and-how-do-they-differ-b)
[Druids](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166176/when-did-druids-make-their-first-appearance-in-dd-and-how-do-they-differ-betwe)
[Rangers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166263/when-did-rangers-make-their-first-appearance-in-dd-and-how-do-they-differ-betw)
[Warlocks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166051/when-did-warlocks-make-their-first-appearance-in-dd-and-how-do-they-differ-betw)

The first line of the help page states:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

There's no problem to solve here.

They're fun research questions that engage the community, but can we throttle them to one a week?

Comment: Aren't RPGs, being *games*, by definition primarily about fun/enjoyment and not about solving 'actual' problems?

Comment: @vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica Yeah, that's the purpose of a game.  What's the purpose of the RPG SE?

Comment: Which means that any endgoals of RPGSE are not solving 'actual problems' in the sense e.g. SO uses the term. Or, conversely, one could argue that achieving enjoyment through RPG-related means is treated as an 'actual problem' for the purposes of RPGSE.

Comment: @vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica So, what's your take on what I'm asking?

Comment: We have a history of gaming tag.  The questions are on topic.  We have version edition questions that are on topic.  We also have a tag for that.  Not sure what problem you are having.  Also, @vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica has a point

Comment: The guidance in the help page is more of a ward against inappropriate open-ended questions, as in practice we generally agree that many question that don't fit into that neat bracket are in fact on-topic. Think of it more as a way to put new users in the right mindset than a genuine restriction. Anyway, at a rate of several a day we would be concerned, but those linked are 4 in 3 days and that's not really a problem.

Comment: @JRodge01 Same as or similar to the first/accepted answer.

Comment: Related: [When I have a series of questions that are unrelated to one another, how much time should I let pass before asking the next/each question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9254/when-i-have-a-series-of-questions-that-are-unrelated-to-one-another-how-much-ti)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## I see no reason to

These questions are interesting! In fact, I just awarded a bounty to aaron9eee for starting them up.

We have always had and allowed questions about lore, history of Subject X across editions, etc. This is no way different and I personally find them interesting.

If you don't like them, downvote if it makes sense for you. Otherwise, just ignore them.

Spacing them out a day apart I think is more than reasonable. It gives time for other questions to feed into the active queue and for new questions to come in on top in the new queue. But I don't see a reason to space it out further.

Comment: The issue isn't that I dislike them!  Just the opposite, I really enjoy them.  I think that asking four in a week means that in a few weeks I'll have exhausted my DND history lessons.  :(

Comment: @JRodge01 Save them for later weeks, and by the time the fourth week rolls around you'll benefit from four weeks of revision having gone into that fourth post.

Comment: And there may be more answers with more content!