# Are there any guidelines on how to interact with game devs on this site?

Tags: discussion, game-designers

So, I was wondering if there are any guidelines on how to interact with game devs who join this site, beyond the normal rules and guidelines of SE - this question being prompted by Dave Brookshaw, the developer of a number of Onyx Path games (including Mage the Awakening), seeming to have registered an account specifically to write an Answer to [one of my Questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150369/has-there-been-any-previous-mentions-of-these-lesser-ministries-before).

I'm pretty sure he's stated before that he's disinclined to write errata or FAQ documents for the Mage without being paid to do so by Onyx Path; are there any guidelines for how to go about interacting with him (or any other game devs from other companies) who might join this site? I'm going to guess that bombarding him with Questions might be interpreted as a breach of netiquette; on the other hand, he might not have much incentive to stick around if no questions in his particular area are asked.

Have any other StackExchange sites like Arqade (the video game SE) dealt with similar situations before? I think some IT companies have used StackExchange as a customer support channel, but I'm not certain if that'd directly analogous to this.

Comment: Related: [To what extent does a well known representative from an RPG company who represents their product need to provide evidence of this in their answers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7342/to-what-extent-does-a-well-known-representative-from-an-rpg-company-who-represen/7345#7345)

Comment: Related: [Is there an established way to handle a game's designer on the site?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/is-there-an-established-way-to-handle-a-games-designer-on-the-site), [How should we handle posts from new users claiming to be notable figures?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/how-should-we-handle-posts-from-new-users-claiming-to-be-notable-figures); semi-related: [Do Authors Overrule Users?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/do-authors-overrule-users)

Comment: On StackOverflow, we have a lot of answer by [@EricLippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) on C# without any trouble. Having him looking around is awesome.

Answer (score 8):

Don't ask unrelated or "follow-up" questions in comments, that's not cool.  Feel free to ask a bajillion follow-up or unrelated questions as *questions*, though, that's totally fine.  It's unlikely, however, you will get Word of God answers to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and they are contained in the [game-designers](/questions/tagged/game-designers) tag that has been placed on this question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't add that tag, V2Blast did.